# Positioning H1 and H2 with CSS

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a css layout. I have the divs #header, #content and #footer inside a #wrapper. The issue is that the explorer shows the h1 and h2 elements inside the #content div, not in #header where these elements actually are. Insofar that increases the top-margin of #content, h1 and h2 go down too. Why could it be happening? 
I would like that this elements stay horizontally aligned (one at right and the other at left) in the same way that the email and the Facebook button are on the footer.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Felipe López</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/es_LA/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=148925589393";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="divisor_izquierda">Felipe López</h1>
        <h2 class="divisor_derecha">DISEÑO WEB</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="content">

        <h3>Hola!</h3>
        <p>Me llamo Felipe y tengo 21 años. Desde los 15 que aprendo Diseño Web como autodidacta y en la actualidad me encuentro cursando la carrera de <a href="#">Diseño de Multimedios</a>. Podés descargar <a href="#">mi Currículum.</a></p>
        <h3>Qué hago?</h3>
        <p>Los sitios web que diseño y programo tienen las siguientes caracteristicas:</p>
        <ul>
        <li>Sistema de autoadministración.</li>
        <li>Posicionamiento en motores de búsqueda.</li>
        <li>Suscripción y envío de newsletters.</li>
        <li>Indexación con redes sociales.</li>
        <li>Sistema de ecommerce.</li>
        </ul>
        <h3>Algunos trabajos</h3>
        <p><a href="#">www.nicolasgolub.com.ar</a><br />
        Diseño, Maquetacion HTML, Cabecera en Flash, Instalación de Wordpress y creación de Tema para Wordpress. Sitio administrado por el cliente.</p>
        <p><a href="#">www.davidaviles.com.ar</a><br />
        Instalación de Wordpress, instalación y modificación de Tema de Wordpress.</p>
        <p><a href="#">www.luzlo.com.ar</a><br />
        Instalación de Wordpress, instalación y modificación de Tema de Wordpress.</p>
        <p><a href="#">www.movpatriotico.com.ar </a><br />
        Maquetacion HTML y Cabecera en Flash.</p>
        <p><a href="#">www.fiestadelaluz.com.ar</a><br />
        Maquetacion HTML y Cabecera en Flash.</p>
        <h3>Contactame</h3>
        <p> Mandame un email a <a href="mailto:&quot;contacto@felipelopez.com.ar&quot;">contacto@felipelopez.com.ar</a> o un mensaje personal por <a href="https://www.facebook.com/unapersona">Facebook</a>.</p>
      </div> 

    <div id="footer">  

    <span class="divisor_izquierda"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.felipelopez.com.ar" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-action="recommend" data-font="arial"></div></span>

    <span class="divisor_derecha"><a href="mailto:&quot;contacto@felipelopez.com.ar&quot;">contacto@felipelopez.com.ar</a></span>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

body {
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-size: 16px; 
}

ul {
    text-transform: none;
}

a {
    font-style: italic;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/*h1 {
    font-size: 36px; 
    position: relative; 
}

h3 {
    margin-top: 20px; 
}

*/

p {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1014px;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    position: relative; 
}

#header {
    position: inherit;
    float: right;
}

#wrapper #header p  {
    color: #F90;
    font-family: Euphemia;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: normal;
    float: left;
    font-size: 36px;
    clear: both;
    width: 50%;
}

#wrapper #header img {
    float: right;
    width: 30%;
}

#content {
    background-color:#FFF;
    padding: 42px;
    padding-bottom: 34px;
    position: relative; 
}

.divisor_izquierda {
    text-align: left;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}
.divisor_derecha {
    text-align: right; 
    float: left;
    width: 50%; 
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can find a variety of solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1633170/423259

Comment: Why are you floating the #header DIV? That's probably what's causing the issues you're seeing. If you mean to do that, you need to make sure your next block element clears the float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you add `overflow: hidden` to the `#header` css, which forces it expand to 'wrap' around its child elements, and does so with no need for extraneous mark-up.

Comment: Well - it works! But I thought "hidden" was supposed to cut outsized content without resizing the parent element. I guess I missed something of the definition...

Comment: Yeah, it confuses me as to *why* it works, too. I put it down to 'magic' and, possibly, 'unicorns.'

Comment: The 'magic'-collection has quite a lot content by now^^ @user1624726: use David's solution unless you have some unexpected behavior with cut off content. My solution works, too, but breaks the separation of content and presentation.

Comment: I used the solution of @DavidThomas, it works well :) But before, i had to change the position of #header as Django said above. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You have floated the headers, therefore the wrapping "header" has no height. Insert a clearing element at the end of the header and your problem should be gone:

```
<div id="header">
        <h1 class="divisor_izquierda">Felipe López</h1>
        <h2 class="divisor_derecha">DISEÑO WEB</h2>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```