# Side menu footer overflow

Tags: css, overflow, footer

I have a webpage with a header, a content, menus, and a footer place.
My content and my menus are in a same div called 'allcontent'. I placed them in the right place with float. (content: float: left; - menus: float:right;)
I added a footer, just with a clear:both style plus some text formating. My problem - as You can see that in the image - the footer isnt at the right place. I placed it after the 'allcontent' div - wich contains the menus divs (!) - but it seems, it is effectless.

What should I do?

[Here is a link to the website](http://eprojekt.srv.hu/e/leftweb/hu/), in the sources You can see more detail of the divs.
Here is the css. wich has anything to do with this:

```
#container {
vertical-align: top;
width: 800px;
text-align: left;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
font-size: 9px;
min-height:100%;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#footer {
background-color: #2D2425;
font-size: 10px;
font-style: normal;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #E2E2E2;
text-align: center;
margin: 40px auto 0;
clear:both;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-top-style:dashed;
border-top-color: #CCC;}


#allcontent {
clear: both;
padding-left: 10px;
min-width: 800px;
min-height: 100%;}
```

*(more in the given website's sources)*
I think these are playing this game.

I did search for sticky footer thingies, but those are for me, I think...
I also have been reading about tricks with padding and margin: no effect.

Sorry for my bad English!
Please try to help me!

Comment: Same problem and solution as here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12147281/positioning-h1-and-h2-with-css/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix by doing the following:

1.) Adding `overflow: hidden` to the `#allcontent` div.

2.) Removing the `height: 135px` from the `#small` div.

Answer (score 0):

don't use float property.
1) delete the `float` property of `#big` and `#small` divs.
2) use `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:top` for them.
3) delete the `height` property of `#small` .